# Angular ui-select2 with AJAX multiselect - retrieve final selection values as ids instead of json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-select2, ui-select2

### Angular ui-select2 with AJAX multiselect - retrieve final selection values as ids instead of json

#### Problem statement

I want to use a tokeninput/chosen/select2 style of ui control to edit an array of ids in my model.  That array of ids is the value of one property in a larger model I'm building an editor/form for.  After editing the array of ids, when I submit the model to the server, I want that property to be submitted as an array of ids, not as an array of json objects.

When using angular's ui-select2 component, the contents of my property get replaced by an array of json objects.  It's not clear how to undo that after editing is complete.  I thought I might be using the wrong component, but all the threads seem to point back to using ui-select2 when doing this kind of thing with angular.

#### Explanation

The data model starts out with a 'myProp' property that's an array of ids:

```
{"myProp":["4","6"]}
```

The ui-select2 directive replaces those ids with json objects.  Here is an example of what the model looks like with ui-select2 loaded. (live demo in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vEf1VwnRHNYdB9AuR9zO ):

```
{"myProp":[{"id":"4","text":"Label for 4"},{"id":"6","text":"Label for 6"},{"id":7,"text":"Seventh","color":"blue"}]}
```

When I save my model, I want this property to be submitted to the server as an array of ids, *not an array of json objects*.  So basically I want to flatten the array back down to just ids instead of json objects.  The select2 API provides a **val** method that would return this array of ids.  How can/should I use it in the context of angular's ui-select2 component?

**Caveat:**I'm doing this multiple times on the page for multiple properties, so a hard-coded fix that is specific to the property will not work.  It has to be something that happens automatically for any proptery I'm editing with select2

#### The Sample Code

(see code in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vEf1VwnRHNYdB9AuR9zO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the select2 directive, I tried changing instances of:

```
    elm.select2('val',
```

to

```
    elm.select2('data',
```

And this worked, but only once you'd added or removed an element. However, by adding

```
    elm.trigger('change');
```

to the initSelection section, this triggers it on loading, which I think should give you your desired behaviour.

[Here's a plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/4WP3PjXxMJ5H0OzUq7rE?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @bcotter  That fixed it.  Time for me to work on getting my head around reading/writing/debugging angular directives.

Comment: Oh.  Sorry.  Your answer fixed it for the OLD version of ui-select2 that was in the plunker, which has other problems in it.  The latest version of ui-select2 is more elaborate and breaks when I apply your fix :-(  See updated plunker with the latest ui-select2 code.  http://plnkr.co/edit/vEf1VwnRHNYdB9AuR9zO

Comment: Right, okay! It seems that you need to just change a line under InitSelection in script.js.

Change where it says:

        response = {id:value, text:"Label for "+value}

To say:

        response = id.value;

http://plnkr.co/edit/NorNbp9oArVZgtEV9MAJ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for helping again.  When I went to report another underlying issue on the ui-select2 github project, I saw this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2/issues/82  Looks like the maintainer is abandoning the component and recommending a complete rewrite.  After 4 days of tinkering, I'm ready to ditch ui-select2 and write something from scratch with JQuery UI tokeninput or Chosen (or pure angular).